# Search spanning non-continuous areas

Tags: vim

I have a list of operations, stages of operation, and URLs. This list looks like this:

```
14257 0 : http://google.com/
14259 0 : http://www.microsoft.com/
14259 1
14259 2
14261 0 : http://www.apple.com/
14261 1
14261 2
14262 0 : http://stackoverflow.com/
14262 1
14263 0 : http://dotancohen.com/
14263 1
14263 2
```

Notice that operations `14257` and `14262` did not get to stage `2`, while the others did.

Consider that the file has already been run through `sort`. Now how can I **reduce the file to only the lines which have not gotten to stage `2`**? Thus, the final file would look as so:

```
14257 0 : http://google.com/
14262 0 : http://stackoverflow.com/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically, you want to delete all lines, that continue on the next 2 lines.
I think, this one does it:

```
g/\v^%(<(\d+)>\D.*\n)%(\1.*\n)%(\1 2)/d 3
```

Then afterwards do one more `v/^\v\d+\D\d\D:/d` and you are left with:

```
14257 0 : http://google.com/
14262 0 : http://stackoverflow.com/
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain the `:g/` line? Even just links to the fine manual would be great. I would like to learn what the `%` is for, and why you start with `\v`. Thanks!

Comment: `\v` means "very magic" mode, that allows to use the usual regex quantifiers without escaping them, which basically means, you can skip a whole bunch of backslashes. `%(` is a way to group the pattern which is usually a little bit faster then the normal `(` grouping, since it doesn't capture the pattern. You can read more about it at `:h /\%v` and `:h /\%(`

Answer (score 1):

You can do a search for all lines that begin with digits, some whitespace and the number `2`. For each match delete that line and the two above it. After that only lines with numbers `0` and `1` will be left, so use a global search and delete every line that doesn't contain a colon:

```
function! DeleteNonContinuous()
    while search( '^\v\d+\s+2', 'W' ) != 0
        execute "normal 2kdelete"
    endwhile
    %v/:/delete
endfunction

command! DNC :call DeleteNonContinuous()
```

Use it like:

```
:DNC
```

That yields:

```
14257 0 : http://google.com/
14262 0 : http://stackoverflow.com/
```